# how to get video id or url after uploading with youtube data v3 php

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have used

```
  $youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet',$video)
```

and

```
var_damp($youtube)
```

and it not show id or url of the video but it give me upload_id. Something I realdy want is id or can I use upload_id instead ?

Comment: why can't you use upload_id?

Comment: I want to know can I use upload_id instead of id or url ? because I need id or url to save in database

Comment: nobody else than you can answer that...